# Magmi Datapump API - Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, magento, magmi, datapump

I am trying to upload products to my Magento store using the Magmi Datapump plugin.

I am currently using the sample code found in: integration > samples > sample.php but it won't add any of my files.

My error log shows the following message for every item in the array.

```
[24-Jul-2015 13:51:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <<HOMEDIR>>/magmi/engines/magmi_productimportengine.php on line 879
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I have tried a few different fixes but none of them worked. I attempted to simply run the script for as long as I could, which then caused a Kernel Panic on my server!